# Xcode's Change Case of Letter shortcut doesn't seem to work

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In Preferences->Key Bindings->Text Key Bindings Xcode has a "Change Case of Letter" key binding. However, when I assign a shortcut to this binding and then attempt to utilize it to swap the case of a letter in one of my source code files, it doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried positioning the cursor before and after the letter, and tried selecting the letter before triggering the assigned shortcut. Nothing seems to do anything.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That had been a general AppKit text function, but was apparently removed several years ago.  I'll update Xcode's text bindings to reflect it.

Instead, write a user script:
[image]
<sub>(source: [mac.com](http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Change%20Case.png))</sub>

and assign it whatever shortcut you want.